# mysql query with two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
posts(id,user_id,event_id}
events(event_id,name,date]}
```

I want to make a query, to retrieve all the names of the events for a particular user_id say id number 2.

In pseudo-code lets say

```
select all the event names from posts where user_id=2
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select events.name from posts, events 
  where posts.event_id = events.event_id and user_id = 2
```

You will need to have something slightly different depending on how you want results with no matches to display.

Answer (score 0):

> select name from events join posts using (event_id) where user_id = 2